# Issue when using _popen windows

Tags: c++

Hello i was try to run execute windows command using _popen and its work fine in vc++ in console.

while same code i do in c++ builder vcl form popen return null pointer ?

vc++

```
std::string exec(const char* cmd) {
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    FILE* pipe = _popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    try {
        while (!feof(pipe)) {
            if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
                result += buffer;
        }
    }
    catch (...) {
        _pclose(pipe);
        throw;
    }
    _pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}
```

c++ builder same as above

```
void __fastcall TForm2::btn_adb_readInfoClick(TObject *Sender) {
    const char* cmd = "D:\\adb\\adb.exe devices";
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    FILE* pipe = _popen(cmd, "r"); // always null
    char* er = strerror(errno);
    try
    {
        if (!pipe) throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
        while (!feof(pipe)) {
            if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
                result += buffer;
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception &ex) {
        _pclose(pipe);
        throw;
    }
    _pclose(pipe);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `errno` immediately following the failed `_popen()`?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: @JohnZwinck errorno is 9 ("bad file number")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx) for `_popen` states:

> If used in a Windows program, the `_popen` function returns an invalid
>   file pointer that causes the program to stop responding indefinitely.
>   `_popen` works properly in a console application.

I'm assuming that C++ Builder is creating a Windows application and not a Console application.

Comment: Yes it was windows application :)

Comment: What is the alternative for a Windows application?

Comment: use a console application under the c++ builder